# There has been a critical error on this website wordpress using xampp

Tags: wordpress, web, xampp

Hey now I just started learning wordpress and I installed xampp as localhost and when I started WordPress in chrome and I gave all the information wt it asked it's showing error

Comment: What does the error log say?  It usually has more information about errors than what are displayed to the web browser.  There is no way to answer this question unless you provide more details.

Comment: If you can please share the files located in C:\xamppp\php\logs, we might be able to help. (assuming you installed the xampp on a windows based machine in C drive).

Comment: here im not able to attach photo its saying i don't have 10 reputation

Comment: seems 500 error in your code or theme files

Comment: You can quote your error log rather than taking a screen shot.

Comment: it's basically showing
There as been critical error on this site
learn more about troubleshooting wordpress

Comment: and I'm using it for 1st time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ As stated by other SO contributors, you have not supplied enough information for anyone to be able to help.  You say that the error message is advising you to 'learn more about troubleshooting Wordpress'. This is probably what you should do.